# Updating an array of objects in redux

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

The initial state looks like this:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    myArray: []
};
```

Now in my reducer, I want to append a new object to the existing array.
I came up with something like this but it doesn't work as expected.

```
    case ADD_TO_ARRAY:
        return {
            ...state,
            myArray: [...state[ { action.payload.key: action.payload.value} ]]
        };
```

Note: I want to create a new object, in line, using the key and value passed in the action payload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with ES6 you can have dynamically calculated object keys
just add a variable to be evaluated in square brackets `[]`

```
case ADD_TO_ARRAY:
  return {
    ...state,
    myArray: [...state.myArray, [ { [action.payload.key]: action.payload.value} ]]
};
```